# Ubuntu does not boot anymore : stucked in grub prompt, boot-repair does not work

Tags: dual-boot, ssd, raid, grubrescue, boot-repair

I have a machine equiped with a hardware RAID and a SSD.

It has a double boot installed, with Ubuntu 16 & Windows 10

When I choose to boot Ubuntu, I just get the grub prompt. After that, I have booted on a live-CD, installed boot-repair and ran it. It said that the reparation succeeded, but after reboot It doesn't solve the problem.

output of fdisk -l :

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.5 GiB, 1553670144 bytes, 3034512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes




Disk /dev/sda: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 33A87EDA-532F-41BF-A202-6032DD4744A1

Device         Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    1026047   1024000   500M EFI System
/dev/sda2    1026048    1288191    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3    1288192  492808191 491520000 234.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  492808192  981106687 488298496 232.9G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  981108736  982030335    921600   450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda6  982030336 1000214527  18184192   8.7G Windows recovery environment


Disk /dev/sdb: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x69ed45fa

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1           1 4294967295 4294967295   2T ee GPT

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/sdc: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


The primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears OK, so that will be used.
Disk /dev/mapper/isw_cjhcigffab_ARRAY0: 3.3 TiB, 3603518717952 bytes, 7038122496 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 131072 bytes / 262144 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 2A78B793-5589-4E95-9F5E-7F98EE161F68

Device                                       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/mapper/isw_cjhcigffab_ARRAY0-part1       2048 6835937279 6835935232  3.2T Linux filesystem
/dev/mapper/isw_cjhcigffab_ARRAY0-part2 6835937280 7038121983  202184704 96.4G Linux swap


Disk /dev/sdd: 15.1 GiB, 16257318912 bytes, 31752576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x1b571474

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1  *          0 3142655 3142656  1.5G  0 Empty
/dev/sdd2       3118960 3123567    4608  2.3M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
```

boot-repair report before fixing : https://pastebin.com/raGBXGrY

boot-repair report after fixing : https://pastebin.com/P3777bBw

Can someone tell me what can I do now to repair grub without shooting any system ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: When you end up in GRUB prompt, does it write anything above the prompt ?

Comment: Nothing else apart standard help msg, actually:

GNU GRUB version2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.1

Minimal BASH-like editing i supported for the first word, TAB list possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.

grub>_